# Tameness of a certain algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be the quiver algebra having 2 points and one loop called $a$ at point 1 and one arrow $1 \rightarrow 2$ called $b$ and relations such that $A$ is a radical square zero algebra.
$A$ is the smallest example of a representation-finite non-Gorenstein quiver algebra. All its Gorenstein projective modules are projective.
Now let $B$ be its enveloping algebra. This is a 16 dimensional algebra with radical cubed zero.

Questions:

1. Is $B$ tame?
2. Can one classify the Gorenstein projective modules of $B$?

Comment: It's not tame, because its separated quiver is not a disjoint union of Dynkin and Euclidean diagrams.

Comment: Thanks. So probably no non-Gorenstein algebra has tame enveloping algebra.